# importing csv file with ocasional empty columns in postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for the best way to import a csv file into a postgresql table, the file contains ,, at some points, which means the corresponding column in the corresponding row must accept 'None' as a value or must remain empty; both which I need help on.
the occurance of ,, in the csv file is not orderly and can not be coded for.

Comment: The table needs to accept `NULL` in a field.  Describe 'empty'(if that does not mean `NULL`), update the question with your answer. Best option is create a staging table that has no constraints on it e.g. no `NOT NULL`  constraints and import to it.

Comment: thank you. the condition of no constraints works for varchar columns but not for int or numeric, which I have. there are double commas ,, in my csv which are recognized as empty fields by postgres and even when there are no constraints for int or numeric columns, an error is raised when reaching those double commas, and that's where i need help. do i need to reformat my csv file first or there's a way to import it as it is?

Comment: i'm using psycopg2 in python by the way, if that's of any importance.

Comment: This will get an answer quicker if you would update your question with: 1) A sample of the CSV data 2) The code you are using to import the CSV 3) The error messages. At a guess the int/numeric errors are coming from `' '`(quoted empty strings) being passed in.

Comment: It may be necessary to define all columns in the staging table as varchar, then, after validating, cast to the appropriate data type when loading from staging to the permanent table.